# Laravel 5 Bulk update records, Mass Update recoreds

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to update or create records. If user has records in database, just update records and if user has no records in database just create records by inputs. Error is

> Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ChoicesController::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

```
public function store(Request $request,$id){
    $time = $request->input('time');
    $user = Choice::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->first();
    if ($user === null) {
        foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
            Choice::create([
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'time'  => $time,
                'topic_id' => $key,
                'question_number' => $value,
            ]);
        }
    }
    else {
        $result = Choice::find($id);
        foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
            $result->user_id = Auth::id();
            $result->time = $request->$time;
            $result->question_number = $request->$value;
            $result->topic_id = $request->$key;
        }
        $result->save();
    }
    return redirect()->route('choices.index');
}
```

These are my routes.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('views.home');

Route::post('tests/custom', 'TestsController@custom')->name('tests.custom');
Route::post('exams/custom', 'ExamsController@custom')->name('exams.custom');
Route::post('laws.store',['as'=>'add.category','uses'=>'LawsController@store']);

Route::resource('laws', 'LawsController');
Route::resource('choices', 'ChoicesController');
Route::resource('legals', 'LegalsController');
Route::resource('faqs', 'FAQsController');
Route::resource('guides', 'GuidesController');
Route::resource('materials', 'MaterialsController');
Route::resource('tests', 'TestsController');
Route::resource('exams_results', 'ExamsResultController');
Route::resource('roles', 'RolesController');
Route::resource('videos', 'VideosController');
Route::resource('exams', 'ExamsController');
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
Route::resource('user_actions', 'UserActionsController');
Route::resource('topics', 'TopicsController');
Route::resource('questions', 'QuestionsController');
Route::resource('questions_options', 'QuestionsOptionsController');
Route::resource('results', 'ResultsController');

Route::post('users_mass_destroy', ['uses' => 'UsersController@massDestroy', 'as' => 'users.mass_destroy']);
Route::post('roles_mass_destroy', ['uses' => 'RolesController@massDestroy', 'as' => 'roles.mass_destroy']);
Route::post('topics_mass_destroy', ['uses' => 'TopicsController@massDestroy', 'as' => 'topics.mass_destroy']);
Route::post('questions_mass_destroy', ['uses' => 'QuestionsController@massDestroy', 'as' => 'questions.mass_destroy']);
Route::post('questions_options_mass_destroy', ['uses' => 'QuestionsOptionsController@massDestroy', 'as' => 'questions_options.mass_destroy']);
Route::post('results_mass_destroy', ['uses' => 'ResultsController@massDestroy', 'as' => 'results.mass_destroy']);

Route::delete('/delete/law/{id}','LawsController@destroy');
});
```

Comment: Show us the route definition from the routes file

Comment: @devk please check out my routes. if u need like `php artisan route:list` let me know.

Comment: How many queries are run for each user? If it's more than one you might want to seriously consider the use of transactions around the queries for each user

Comment: I don't understand can u make it clear to me? Or can you show me example of that?

Comment: Routes seem correct. Can you try adding another parameter to `store` method: `store(Request $request, $id, $test)` and dumping them with `dd([$id, $test])`

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems related route, Normally store function get only one parameter that this "Request $id", but yours, get both $request and $id. Therefore error occurred,

Standard resources store function must be like this,

```
public function store (Request $request)
```

For solution,

You should send "$id" with request

or

You should add new route for this store function like this

```
Route::post('choices/{id}', 'ChoicesController@store')
```

I think, solution 1 is better than 2

I hope this will help

Answer (score -1):

You are using resource routes so you can not pass $id argument in store action.

You can use firstOrCreate() provided by laravel itself.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#other-creation-methods